# Parsing huge logfiles in Node.js - read in line-by-line

Tags: node.js, parsing, logfile-analysis

I need to do some parsing of large (5-10 Gb)logfiles in Javascript/Node.js (I'm using Cube).

The logline looks something like:

```
10:00:43.343423 I'm a friendly log message. There are 5 cats, and 7 dogs. We are in state "SUCCESS".
```

We need to read each line, do some parsing (e.g. strip out `5`, `7` and `SUCCESS`), then pump this data into Cube (https://github.com/square/cube) using their JS client.

Firstly, what is the canonical way in Node to read in a file, line by line?

It seems to be fairly common question online:

- http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-node-js
- [Read a file one line at a time in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156501/read-a-file-one-line-at-a-time-in-node-js)

A lot of the answers seem to point to a bunch of third-party modules:

- https://github.com/nickewing/line-reader
- https://github.com/jahewson/node-byline
- https://github.com/pkrumins/node-lazy
- https://github.com/Gagle/Node-BufferedReader

However, this seems like a fairly basic task - surely, there's a simple way within the stdlib to read in a textfile, line-by-line?

Secondly, I then need to process each line (e.g. convert the timestamp into a Date object, and extract useful fields).

What's the best way to do this, maximising throughput? Is there some way that won't block on either reading in each line, or on sending it to Cube?

Thirdly - I'm guessing using string splits, and the JS equivalent of contains (IndexOf != -1?) will be a lot faster than regexes? Has anybody had much experience in parsing massive amounts of text data in Node.js?

Comment: I built a log parser in node that takes a bunch of regex strings with 'captures' built in and outputs to JSON.  You can even call functions on each capture if you want to do a calc.  It might do what you want:  **https://npmjs.org/package/logax**

Comment: A better comparison https://betterprogramming.pub/a-memory-friendly-way-of-reading-files-in-node-js-a45ad0cc7bb6

Answer (score 250, accepted):

I searched for a solution to parse very large files (gbs) line by line using a stream. All the third-party libraries and examples did not suit my needs since they processed the files not line by line (like 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ..) or read the entire file to memory

The following solution can parse very large files, line by line using stream & pipe. For testing I used a 2.1 gb file with 17.000.000 records. Ram usage did not exceed 60 mb.

First, install the [event-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-stream) package:

```
npm install event-stream
```

Then:

```
var fs = require('fs')
    , es = require('event-stream');

var lineNr = 0;

var s = fs.createReadStream('very-large-file.csv')
    .pipe(es.split())
    .pipe(es.mapSync(function(line){

        // pause the readstream
        s.pause();

        lineNr += 1;

        // process line here and call s.resume() when rdy
        // function below was for logging memory usage
        logMemoryUsage(lineNr);

        // resume the readstream, possibly from a callback
        s.resume();
    })
    .on('error', function(err){
        console.log('Error while reading file.', err);
    })
    .on('end', function(){
        console.log('Read entire file.')
    })
);
```

[image]

Please let me know how it goes!

Comment: FYI, this code isn't synchronous.  It's asynchronous.  If you insert `console.log(lineNr)` after the last line of your code, it will not show the final line count because the file is read asynchronously.

Comment: what is logMemoryUsage(lineNr);  or how to get data of the lineNr in the file

if i try to print lineNr with my file i am getting only number 2 and there are 6000 records

Comment: Hi Labeo, it was a function I used to log memory usage but it's not included in the code. You can remove that line from the code.

Comment: Thank you, this was the only solution I could find that actually paused and resumed when it was supposed to. Readline didn't.

Comment: Awesome example, and it does actually pause.  Additionally if you decide to stop the file read early you can use `s.end();`

Comment: What's the benefit of have pause and resume? I don't think my typical uses would need that unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I was wondering what's the point of having resume inside an anonymous function?

Comment: @ambodi it served no purpose, I removed the function.

Comment: @ambodi, I believe the purpose of pause/resume is to allow other asynchronous processes to happen before continuing to read from the file.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Used it to index 150 million documents to elasticsearch index. `readline` module is a pain. It does not pause and was causing failure everytime after 40-50 million. Wasted a day. Thanks a lot for the answer. This one works perfectly

Comment: I use this for parsing log files, and for lines that I skip it can get ahead of itself and result in a stackoverflow. If there isn't work for every line be wary of this, because it might end up failing.

Comment: In case you run out of heap memory you can use below command format
node --max_old_space_size=4096 app.js

Comment: The `pause` and `result` would only be useful if `resume` was called from a callback, or if the containing function was `async` and `await`s were used between the `pause` and `resume` methods

Comment: How I'll be writing to another stream. My requirement is to read heavy JSON data from db in GB's and write it to excel file. If using your code then i need to push data into writable excel stream. please guide @Gerard

Comment: event-stream was compromised: https://medium.com/intrinsic/compromised-npm-package-event-stream-d47d08605502 but 4+ is apparently safe https://blog.npmjs.org/post/180565383195/details-about-the-event-stream-incident

Comment: Not one of ```s.end(); s.destroy(); s.emit('end'); ``` will stop stream from reading. It takes  25sec to read 1 line of 5Gig file from a SSD drive (because the stream reader does not stop). See line-by-line answer for a solution that did this in 1ms (using ```s.cancel()```).

Comment: You are a god, please name my daughter.

Answer (score 89):

You can use the inbuilt `readline` package, see docs [here](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html). I use [stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) to create a new output stream.

```js
    var fs = require('fs'),
        readline = require('readline'),
        stream = require('stream');
    
    var instream = fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file');
    var outstream = new stream;
    outstream.readable = true;
    outstream.writable = true;
    
    var rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: instream,
        output: outstream,
        terminal: false
    });
    
    rl.on('line', function(line) {
        console.log(line);
        //Do your stuff ...
        //Then write to output stream
        rl.write(line);
    });
```

Large files will take some time to process. Do tell if it works.

Comment: As written, the second to last line fails because cubestuff is not defined.

Comment: Using `readline`, is it possible to pause/resume the read stream to perform async actions in the "do stuff" area?

Comment: @jchook `readline` was giving me a lot of problems when I tried pause/resume. It does not pause the stream properly creating a lot of problem if the downstream process is slower

Answer (score 35):

I really liked [@gerard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494601/gerard) answer which is actually deserves to be the correct answer here. I made some improvements:

- Code is in a class (modular)
- Parsing is included
- Ability to resume is given to the outside in case there is an asynchronous job is chained to reading the CSV like inserting to DB, or a HTTP request
- Reading in chunks/batche sizes that
  user can declare. I took care of encoding in the stream too, in case
  you have files in different encoding.

Here's the code:

```
'use strict'

const fs = require('fs'),
    util = require('util'),
    stream = require('stream'),
    es = require('event-stream'),
    parse = require("csv-parse"),
    iconv = require('iconv-lite');

class CSVReader {
  constructor(filename, batchSize, columns) {
    this.reader = fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(iconv.decodeStream('utf8'))
    this.batchSize = batchSize || 1000
    this.lineNumber = 0
    this.data = []
    this.parseOptions = {delimiter: '\t', columns: true, escape: '/', relax: true}
  }

  read(callback) {
    this.reader
      .pipe(es.split())
      .pipe(es.mapSync(line => {
        ++this.lineNumber

        parse(line, this.parseOptions, (err, d) => {
          this.data.push(d[0])
        })

        if (this.lineNumber % this.batchSize === 0) {
          callback(this.data)
        }
      })
      .on('error', function(){
          console.log('Error while reading file.')
      })
      .on('end', function(){
          console.log('Read entirefile.')
      }))
  }

  continue () {
    this.data = []
    this.reader.resume()
  }
}

module.exports = CSVReader
```

So basically, here is how you will use it:

```
let reader = CSVReader('path_to_file.csv')
reader.read(() => reader.continue())
```

I tested this with a 35GB CSV file and it worked for me and that's why I chose to build it on  [@gerard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494601/gerard)'s answer, feedbacks are welcomed.

Comment: how much time it took?

Comment: Apparently, this lacks `pause()` call, doesn't it?

Comment: Also, this doesn't call callback function on end. So if batchSize is 100, size of files is 150, only 100 items would be processed. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 25):

I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-by-line for reading more than 1 000 000 lines from a text file. In this case, an occupied capacity of RAM was about 50-60 megabyte.

```
    const LineByLineReader = require('line-by-line'),
    lr = new LineByLineReader('big_file.txt');

    lr.on('error', function (err) {
         // 'err' contains error object
    });

    lr.on('line', function (line) {
        // pause emitting of lines...
        lr.pause();

        // ...do your asynchronous line processing..
        setTimeout(function () {
            // ...and continue emitting lines.
            lr.resume();
        }, 100);
    });

    lr.on('end', function () {
         // All lines are read, file is closed now.
    });
```

Comment: 'line-by-line' is more memory efficient than the selected answer. For 1 million lines in a csv the selected answer had my node process in the low 800s of megabytes. Using 'line-by-line' it was consistently in the low 700s. This module also keeps the code clean and easy to read. In total I will need to read about 18 million so every mb counts!

Comment: it's a shame this uses it's own event 'line' instead of the standard 'chunk', meaning you won't be able to make use of 'pipe'.

Comment: After hours of testing and searching this is the only solution that actually stop on ```lr.cancel()``` method. Reads first 1000 lines of a 5Gig file in 1ms. Awesome!!!!

Answer (score 20):

The Node.js Documentation offers a very elegant example using the Readline module.

[Example: Read File Stream Line-by-Line](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line)

```js
const { once } = require('node:events');
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('sample.txt'),
    crlfDelay: Infinity
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
});

await once(rl, 'close');
```

> Note: we use the crlfDelay option to recognize all instances of CR LF ('\r\n') as a single line break.

Comment: In my case, I want to show the entire text in an HTML using an element's `innerHTML`, but the last line is always cut off, even if I have `overflow: auto` in my css. What's wrong?

Comment: OK, I got it. I got to use a bigger `padding-bottom` than my `padding` parameter.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of using 'readline'. Why can't we just do it using readStream?

Answer (score 8):

Apart from read the big file line by line, you also can read it chunk by chunk. For more refer to [this article](http://www.scriptol.com/javascript/node-readline.php)

```
var offset = 0;
var chunkSize = 2048;
var chunkBuffer = new Buffer(chunkSize);
var fp = fs.openSync('filepath', 'r');
var bytesRead = 0;
while(bytesRead = fs.readSync(fp, chunkBuffer, 0, chunkSize, offset)) {
    offset += bytesRead;
    var str = chunkBuffer.slice(0, bytesRead).toString();
    var arr = str.split('\n');

    if(bytesRead = chunkSize) {
        // the last item of the arr may be not a full line, leave it to the next chunk
        offset -= arr.pop().length;
    }
    lines.push(arr);
}
console.log(lines);
```

Comment: Could it be, that the following should be a comparison instead of an assignment: `if(bytesRead = chunkSize)`?

Answer (score 6):

**Reading / Writing files** using stream with the native nodejs modules (**fs, readline**):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
                                       input:  fs.createReadStream('input.json'),
                                       output: fs.createWriteStream('output.json')
                                    });

rl.on('line', function(line) {
    console.log(line);

    // Do any 'line' processing if you want and then write to the output file
    this.output.write(`${line}\n`);
});

rl.on('close', function() {
    console.log(`Created "${this.output.path}"`);
});
```

Comment: nice and clean !

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem yet. After comparing several modules that seem to have this feature, I decided to do it myself, it's simpler than I thought.

gist: https://gist.github.com/deemstone/8279565

```
var fetchBlock = lineByline(filepath, onEnd);
fetchBlock(function(lines, start){ ... });  //lines{array} start{int} lines[0] No.
```

It cover the file opened in a closure, that `fetchBlock()` returned will fetch a block from the file, end split to array (will deal the segment from last fetch).

I've set the block size to 1024 for each read operation. This may have bugs, but code logic is obvious, try it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545147/nodejs-synchronization-read-large-file-line-by-line) questions answer I implemented a class you can use to read a file synchronously line-by-line with `fs.readSync()`. You can make this "pause" and "resume" by using a `Q` promise (`jQuery` seems to require a DOM so cant run it with `nodejs`):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Q = require('q');

var lr = new LineReader(filenameToLoad);
lr.open();

var promise;
workOnLine = function () {
    var line = lr.readNextLine();
    promise = complexLineTransformation(line).then(
        function() {console.log('ok');workOnLine();},
        function() {console.log('error');}
    );
}
workOnLine();

complexLineTransformation = function (line) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    // ... async call goes here, in callback: deferred.resolve('done ok'); or deferred.reject(new Error(error));
    return deferred.promise;
}

function LineReader (filename) {      
  this.moreLinesAvailable = true;
  this.fd = undefined;
  this.bufferSize = 1024*1024;
  this.buffer = new Buffer(this.bufferSize);
  this.leftOver = '';

  this.read = undefined;
  this.idxStart = undefined;
  this.idx = undefined;

  this.lineNumber = 0;

  this._bundleOfLines = [];

  this.open = function() {
    this.fd = fs.openSync(filename, 'r');
  };

  this.readNextLine = function () {
    if (this._bundleOfLines.length === 0) {
      this._readNextBundleOfLines();
    }
    this.lineNumber++;
    var lineToReturn = this._bundleOfLines[0];
    this._bundleOfLines.splice(0, 1); // remove first element (pos, howmany)
    return lineToReturn;
  };

  this.getLineNumber = function() {
    return this.lineNumber;
  };

  this._readNextBundleOfLines = function() {
    var line = "";
    while ((this.read = fs.readSync(this.fd, this.buffer, 0, this.bufferSize, null)) !== 0) { // read next bytes until end of file
      this.leftOver += this.buffer.toString('utf8', 0, this.read); // append to leftOver
      this.idxStart = 0
      while ((this.idx = this.leftOver.indexOf("\n", this.idxStart)) !== -1) { // as long as there is a newline-char in leftOver
        line = this.leftOver.substring(this.idxStart, this.idx);
        this._bundleOfLines.push(line);        
        this.idxStart = this.idx + 1;
      }
      this.leftOver = this.leftOver.substring(this.idxStart);
      if (line !== "") {
        break;
      }
    }
  }; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

node-byline uses streams, so i would prefer that one for your huge files.

for your date-conversions i would use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

for maximising your throughput you could think about using a software-cluster. there are some nice-modules which wrap the node-native cluster-module quite well. i like [cluster-master](https://npmjs.org/package/cluster-master) from isaacs. e.g. you could create a cluster of x workers which all compute a file.

for benchmarking splits vs regexes use [benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com). i havent tested it until now. benchmark.js is available as a node-module

Comment: Note `moment.js` nowadays has fallen out of favor due to significant performance concerns, namely: its gargantuan footprint, inability to tree shake, and deeply entrenched but now widely disliked mutability. Even [its own devs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) have all but written it off. Some good alternatives are `date-fns` and `day.js`; here's an article with more details: <https://www.skypack.dev/blog/2021/02/the-best-javascript-date-libraries/>

Answer (score 1):

```js
import * as csv from 'fast-csv';
import * as fs from 'fs';
interface Row {
  [s: string]: string;
}
type RowCallBack = (data: Row, index: number) => object;
export class CSVReader {
  protected file: string;
  protected csvOptions = {
    delimiter: ',',
    headers: true,
    ignoreEmpty: true,
    trim: true
  };
  constructor(file: string, csvOptions = {}) {
    if (!fs.existsSync(file)) {
      throw new Error(`File ${file} not found.`);
    }
    this.file = file;
    this.csvOptions = Object.assign({}, this.csvOptions, csvOptions);
  }
  public read(callback: RowCallBack): Promise < Array < object >> {
    return new Promise < Array < object >> (resolve => {
      const readStream = fs.createReadStream(this.file);
      const results: Array < any > = [];
      let index = 0;
      const csvStream = csv.parse(this.csvOptions).on('data', async (data: Row) => {
        index++;
        results.push(await callback(data, index));
      }).on('error', (err: Error) => {
        console.error(err.message);
        throw err;
      }).on('end', () => {
        resolve(results);
      });
      readStream.pipe(csvStream);
    });
  }
}
```

```js
import { CSVReader } from '../src/helpers/CSVReader';
(async () => {
  const reader = new CSVReader('./database/migrations/csv/users.csv');
  const users = await reader.read(async data => {
    return {
      username: data.username,
      name: data.name,
      email: data.email,
      cellPhone: data.cell_phone,
      homePhone: data.home_phone,
      roleId: data.role_id,
      description: data.description,
      state: data.state,
    };
  });
  console.log(users);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @gerard 's answer, and I want to provide a controlled way of reading chunk by chunk.

I have an electron app, which read multiple large log files chunk by chunk on user's request, the next chunk will only be requested when user asking for it.

Here is my LogReader class

```
// A singleton class, used to read log chunk by chunk
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { logDirPath } from './mainConfig';
import * as path from 'path';

type ICallback = (data: string) => Promise<void> | void;

export default class LogReader {
  filenames: string[];
  readstreams: fs.ReadStream[];
  chunkSize: number;
  lineNumber: number;
  data: string;

  static instance: LogReader;

  private constructor(chunkSize = 10240) {
    this.chunkSize = chunkSize || 10240; // default to 10kB per chunk
    this.filenames = [];
    // collect all log files and sort from latest to oldest
    fs.readdirSync(logDirPath).forEach((file) => {
      if (file.endsWith('.log')) {
        this.filenames.push(path.join(logDirPath, file));
      }
    });

    this.filenames = this.filenames.sort().reverse();
    this.lineNumber = 0;
  }

  static getInstance() {
    if (!this.instance) {
      this.instance = new LogReader();
    }

    return this.instance;
  }

  // read a chunk from a log file
  read(fileIndex: number, chunkIndex: number, cb: ICallback) {
    // file index out of range, return "end of all files"
    if (fileIndex >= this.filenames.length) {
      cb('EOAF');
      return;
    }

    const chunkSize = this.chunkSize;
    fs.createReadStream(this.filenames[fileIndex], {
      highWaterMark: chunkSize, // 1kb per read
      start: chunkIndex * chunkSize, // start byte of this chunk
      end: (chunkIndex + 1) * chunkSize - 1, // end byte of this chunk (end index was included, so minus 1)
    })
      .on('data', (data) => {
        cb(data.toString());
      })
      .on('error', (e) => {
        console.error('Error while reading file.');
        console.error(e);
        cb('EOF');
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log('Read entire chunk.');
        cb('EOF');
      });
  }
}
```

Then to read chunk by chunk, the main process just need to call:

```
  const readLogChunk = (fileIndex: number, chunkIndex: number): Promise<string> => {
    console.log(`=== load log chunk ${fileIndex}: ${chunkIndex}====`);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      LogReader.getInstance().read(fileIndex, chunkIndex, (data) => resolve(data));
    });
  };
```

Keep increment chunkIndex to read chunk by chunk

When `EOF` is returned, means one file finished, just increment the fileIndex,

When `EOAF` is returned, means all files are read, just stop.

Answer (score -2):

I have made a node module to read large file asynchronously text or JSON.
Tested on large files.

```
var fs = require('fs')
, util = require('util')
, stream = require('stream')
, es = require('event-stream');

module.exports = FileReader;

function FileReader(){

}

FileReader.prototype.read = function(pathToFile, callback){
    var returnTxt = '';
    var s = fs.createReadStream(pathToFile)
    .pipe(es.split())
    .pipe(es.mapSync(function(line){

        // pause the readstream
        s.pause();

        //console.log('reading line: '+line);
        returnTxt += line;        

        // resume the readstream, possibly from a callback
        s.resume();
    })
    .on('error', function(){
        console.log('Error while reading file.');
    })
    .on('end', function(){
        console.log('Read entire file.');
        callback(returnTxt);
    })
);
};

FileReader.prototype.readJSON = function(pathToFile, callback){
    try{
        this.read(pathToFile, function(txt){callback(JSON.parse(txt));});
    }
    catch(err){
        throw new Error('json file is not valid! '+err.stack);
    }
};
```

Just save the file as file-reader.js, and use it like this:

```
var FileReader = require('./file-reader');
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.readJSON(__dirname + '/largeFile.json', function(jsonObj){/*callback logic here*/});
```

Comment: I looks like you copied from Gerard's answer.  You should give Gerard credit for the part you copied.