# How to read a file line by line in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-io

This question is a continuation of a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20719482/1085699).  I wrote the following piece of code to determine if `File.openRead()` created a Stream that could be streamed line-by-line.  It turns out that the answer is no.  The entire file is read and then passed to the next transform.  My question is then:  How do you Stream a file line-by-line in Dart?

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';


void main(List<String> arguments) {

  Stream<List<int>> stream = new File('Data.txt').openRead();

   stream
      .transform(const Utf8InterceptDecoder())
        .transform(const LineSplitterIntercept())
          .listen((line) {
//            stdout.writeln(line);
          }).asFuture().catchError((_) => print(_));
}

int lineSplitCount = 0;

class LineSplitterIntercept extends LineSplitter {

  const LineSplitterIntercept() : super();
  // Never gets called
  List<String> convert(String data) {
    stdout.writeln("LineSplitterIntercept.convert : Data:" + data);
    return super.convert(data);
  }

  StringConversionSink startChunkedConversion(ChunkedConversionSink<String> sink) {
    stdout.writeln("LineSplitterIntercept.startChunkedConversion Count:"+lineSplitCount.toString()+ " Sink: " + sink.toString());
    lineSplitCount++;
    return super.startChunkedConversion(sink);
  }
}

int utfCount = 0;

class Utf8InterceptDecoder extends Utf8Decoder {

  const Utf8InterceptDecoder() : super();

  //never gets called
  String convert(List<int> codeUnits) {
    stdout.writeln("Utf8InterceptDecoder.convert : codeUnits.length:" + codeUnits.length.toString());
    return super.convert(codeUnits);
  }


  ByteConversionSink startChunkedConversion(ChunkedConversionSink<String> sink) {
    stdout.writeln("Utf8InterceptDecoder.startChunkedConversion Count:"+ utfCount.toString() + " Sink: "+ sink.toString());
    utfCount++;
    return super.startChunkedConversion(sink);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The converter's `startChunkedConversion` is only called once, when the transformation is started. However, the returned sink's `add` method is invoked multiple times with parts of the file.

It's up to the source to decide how big the chunks are, but a 37MB file (as mentioned in your previous question) will definitely be sent in smaller chunks.

If you want to see the chunks you can either intercept `startChunkedConversion` and return a wrapped sink, or you can put yourself between the `openRead` and the transformer.

Intercept:

```dart
class InterceptSink {
  static int lineSplitCount = 0;

  final _sink;
  InterceptSink(this._sink);
  add(x) {
    print("InterceptSink.add Count: $lineSplitCount");
    lineSplitCount++;
    _sink.add(x);
  }
  close() { _sink.close(); }
}

class LineSplitterIntercept extends Converter {
  convert(x) { throw "unimplemented"; }
  startChunkedConversion(outSink) {
    var lineSink = new LineSplitter().startChunkedConversion(outSink);
    return new InterceptSink(lineSink);
  }
}
```

After `openRead`:

```dart
file.openRead()
  .transform(UTF8.decoder)
  .map(x) {
    print("chunk size: ${x.length)");
    return x;
  }
  .transform(new LineSplitter())
  ...
```

Comment: The transforms execute and then pass the entire result on to the next transform.  Is there a way to chain the transforms to the line level without overriding the sink?  On a (http) server, this kind of memory consumption would be unacceptable.

Comment: Not with transformers and `File.openRead()`. There the source decides on the most efficient size of the chunks. You can, however, use `File.open` which returns a `RandomAccessFile`. There, you can read byte by byte, if you need to.

Comment: For documentation only: I opened this as an issue with the Dart team and they showed an interesting solution. See: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15828 (And I do see the irony Florian)

Answer (score 7):

I think this code is useful:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

main() {
  final file = new File('file.txt');
  Stream<List<int>> inputStream = file.openRead();

  inputStream
    .transform(utf8.decoder)       // Decode bytes to UTF-8.
    .transform(new LineSplitter()) // Convert stream to individual lines.
    .listen((String line) {        // Process results.
        print('$line: ${line.length} bytes');
      },
      onDone: () { print('File is now closed.'); },
      onError: (e) { print(e.toString()); });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If a stream is necessary, you can create it from the future that `readAsLines()` returns:

```
   Stream<List<String>> stream = 
      new Stream.fromFuture(new File('Data.txt').readAsLines());
```

However it looks simpler to me to plainly process the lines one by one,

```
  List<String> lines = new File('Data.txt').readAsLinesSync();
  for (var line in lines) {
    stdout.writeln(line); 
  }
```

Comment: The first piece of code still loads the data all at once despite it's name. @Florian Loitsch shows how to break it apart. In your second piece of code, the entire file is read into `lines` before proceeding.  I only want to read a single line, process it, and then discard.

Answer (score 2):

Because none of the other answers suited my situation, here is another technique:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';


void main()
{
    var file = File('/path/to/some/file.txt');
    var raf = file.openSync(mode: fileMode.read);
 
    String line;
    while ((line = readLine(raf)) != null)
    {
        print(line);
    }
  }

  String readLine(RandomAccessFile raf, {String lineDelimiter = '\n'}) {
 
    var line = '';
    int byte;
    var priorChar = '';

    var foundDelimiter = false;

    while ((byte = raf.readByteSync()) != -1) {
      var char = utf8.decode([byte]);

      if (isLineDelimiter(priorChar, char, lineDelimiter)) {
        foundDelimiter = true;
        break;
      }

      line += char;
      priorChar = char;
    }
    if (line.isEmpty && foundDelimiter == false) {
      line = null;
    }
    return line;
  }


  bool isLineDelimiter(String priorChar, String char, String lineDelimiter) {
    if (lineDelimiter.length == 1) {
      return char == lineDelimiter;
    } else {
      return priorChar + char == lineDelimiter;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting [Brett Sutton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59558679/21006357) for sound null safety and wider availability:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

bool isLineDelimiter(String priorChar, String char, String lineDelimiter) 
{
  if (lineDelimiter.length == 1) {
    return char == lineDelimiter;
  } else {
    return priorChar + char == lineDelimiter;
  }
}

/// Reads one line and returns its contents.
///
/// If end-of-file has been reached and the line is empty null is returned.
String? readLine(RandomAccessFile raf,
    {String lineDelimiter = '\n', void Function()? onEOF}) {
  String line = '';
  int byte;
  String priorChar = '';
  byte = raf.readByteSync();
  while (byte != -1) {
    String char = utf8.decode([byte]);
    if (isLineDelimiter(priorChar, char, lineDelimiter)) return line;
    line += char;
    priorChar = char;
    byte = raf.readByteSync();
  }
  onEOF?.call();
  if (line.isEmpty) return null;
  return line;
}
```

EDIT 1:

I wanted to add some more line-specific functions I made:

```
/// Skips one line and returns the last byte read.
///
/// If end-of-file has been reached -1 is returned.
int skipLine(RandomAccessFile raf,
    {String lineDelimiter = '\n', void Function()? onEOF}) {
  int byte;
  String priorChar = '';
  byte = raf.readByteSync();
  while (byte != -1) {
    String char = utf8.decode([byte]);
    if (isLineDelimiter(priorChar, char, lineDelimiter)) return byte;
    priorChar = char;
    byte = raf.readByteSync();
  }
  return byte;
}

/// Reads all lines in the file and executes [onLine] per each.
///
/// If [onLine] returns true the function terminates.
void processLines(
  RandomAccessFile raf, {
  String lineDelimiter = '\n',
  required bool? Function(String line, bool eofReached) onLine,
}) {
  bool _eofReached = false;
  do {
    String? _line;
    _line = readLine(raf,
        lineDelimiter: lineDelimiter, onEOF: () => _eofReached = true);
    if (_line == null) return;
    if (onLine(_line, _eofReached) == true) return;
  } while (!_eofReached);
}
```