# Javascript: How to write records into a file line by line separated by a comma but without a trailing comma at the end

Tags: javascript

I've got a file of records (one per line):

```
Record1
Record2
Record3
```

I'm using the `fs` and the `readline` modules for that:

```
        const rs = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');
        const ws = fs.createWriteStream('output.json', { encoding: "utf8" });
        const rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: rs,
            crlfDelay: Infinity,
        });
        ws.write('[');
        for await (const line of rl) {
            ws.write(`${line},\n`);
        }
        ws.end(']');
```

But this loop will also toss in a trailing comma at the end of the file which is bad cos trailing commas are not allowed in JSON.

The problem is that I don't want to read the whole file into memory and I don't know the number of records in advance.

Edit:

This is a simple example, but in the real code, the record gets transformed to a json record, but it's irrelevant.

Comment: If the file is too large for memory, is it practical to output one huge JSON file? Assuming the consumer must repeat the streaming ingestion process, why not use [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/)/[ndjson](http://ndjson.org/) instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36749787/11134160

Comment: @jsejcksn Thank you. The requirement is to use an ordinary json file. =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By creating a local variable to track whether you've already encountered the first record, you can prepend the comma to all entries after the first one, achieving the same effect:

> Note that, because whitespace is insignificant in JSON, you will decrease the size of the resulting file by omitting the newlines

```js
ws.write('[');

let comma = false;

for await (const line of rl) {
  if (!line.trim()) continue;
  if (comma) ws.write(',');
  ws.write(line);
  comma = true;
}

ws.end(']');
```

Comment: Could be further simplified to just using a boolean flag if you aren't using the line number for anything. Saves wasting compute on calculating that number (however insignificant that difference is)

Comment: @samthecodingman Good optimization; updated

Comment: Great answer, thank you.  But it still puts a comma when there's only one record.

Comment: @one_tit_shark The updated conditional should handle the case where the line is empty. My guess is that `readline` still iterates on the final (empty) line of the input.

Comment: @jsejcksn Hmm yeah seems so. Thanks for the update!