# NodeJS: reading a big csv file

Tags: json, node.js, regex, readfile, fs

So I have a 70mb .csv file that I wanna parse and convert into a json, trying to do the json convert in a 500kb test csv I found an easy solution with regex.
The problem was when I put my actual data, I can't use fs.readFileSync anymore, so I need to work with streams.
My problem is: how can I work with streams and regex? Supose that my stream cuts the buffer in the middle of a possible regex match, I think if that happens I will lose that data. Also, the data isn't structured so I don't realise other way to parse it than regexs.
Please let me know if I wasn't clear with my explanation, english isn't my main language but also I know the english community is the biggest also the fastest and more reliable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you're using node for this? From my experience Python or R is much more suited for the task.

Comment: Why would stream cut the buffer ? Read line by line like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010915/parsing-huge-logfiles-in-node-js-read-in-line-by-line

Comment: @spicypumpkin because it's a single time task and i'm more familiar with js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is a stable [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) core module

and you can do this

```
let lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('file.csv')
})

lineReader.on('line', (line) => {
  // do regexs with line
})
```