# Node is crashing while trying to get more then 500kb text/json data from cpp dll

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management, ffi, node-ffi

//cpp code

```
ifstream myfile;

myfile.open("D:\Spot\data\simpledata.txt");

string content((std::istreambuf_iterator(myfile)),
(istreambuf_iterator()));
myfile.close();
char* chr = &content[0];
return char;
```

//node code

```
var libSpotcolor = ffi.Library(fileName, {
'test': ["char *", []]
});

var testdata =libSpotcolor.test(); // Here node is crashing

console.log(testdata);

var save_json = testdata.readCString();
```

can i get more the 1 mb data ,
If not is any alternate way to get this ?

Comment: Why don't you use node [filesystem module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) ?

Comment: Hi, there are 3rd party software:
https://github.com/nickewing/line-reader

https://github.com/jahewson/node-byline

https://github.com/pkrumins/node-lazy
https://github.com/Gagle/Node-BufferedReader

Comment: Already answered
Ref: [Parsing huge file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23695940/8281584)

Comment: i have to get data from dll and store into a variable.So i dont want to use filesystem module.node-ffi is a Node.js addon for loading and calling dynamic libraries using pure JavaScript.

Comment: `any alternative`  Like @SergeK. says, using node would be the best option.  There are thousands of NPM modules nowadays.  Saying this, for the rare occasions I have had to integrate with none node stuff, the best option I've found is using Stdio, you basically create a simple protocol to send the information between them, stdio is fast & cross platform too.

Comment: Could you provide details about the crash?

Comment: Thank you eveybody. i found the problem. The problem memory was deallocation. So i got the idea from http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/string_return/ and implemented in cpp