# Node js - line by line file reading with buffered output

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been struggling for 6 days just to find a solution which can give me buffered output of a given large file. The file can be text, binary, etc.

The code below gives a buffered output of only small files. Providing large files makes it crash.

```
var fs = require('fs')

var stream = fs.createReadStream('big-file')

stream.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data)
})
```

I also tried using 'byline' library

```
var fs = require('fs')
var byline = require('byline')

var stream = fs.createReadStream('big-file')

var buffered_stream = byline.createStream(stream, { keepEmptyLines : true )

buffered_stream.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data)
})
```

It gives the buffered output of each line but the bytes are corrupted because extended ASCII characters are multi-bye characters.

If someone can, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the awful formatting, but can you try something like this and see if there's something wrong with the file? `/* This will wait until we know the readable stream is actually valid before piping */
  readStream.on('open', function () {
    /* This just pipes the read stream to the response object (which goes to the client) */
    readStream.pipe(res);
  });

  /* This catches any errors that happen while creating the readable stream (usually invalid names) */
  readStream.on('error', function(err) {
    res.end(err);
  });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156501/read-a-file-one-line-at-a-time-in-node-js?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny but I got the answer the next minute I posted this question. Sorry for the delay in update. The code below outputs buffer of each line of the specified file (big or small).

```
var fs = require('fs')
var lazy = require('lazy')

var readStream = fs.createReadStream('FILE')

new lazy(readStream)
    .lines
    .forEach(function(line) {
        console.log(line) // Buffer
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_readable_stream) the default `highWatermark` property of the stream is equivalent to a maximal file size of 16kb. It does not mean you should change its size, but to concat the buffers as shown:

```
const fs = require('fs');

var stream = fs.createReadStream(BIG_FILE);

let buffers = [];;
stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
    const buf = Buffer.from(chunk)
    buffers.push(chunk);
})

stream.on('end', () => {
    console.log(Buffer.concat(buffers));
})
```

Comment: bombyx mori, I tried using your code but it has the same problem which my code has. Hangs on big files. I tried it on a 700 mb exe. This happens because the size of the array which you specified keeps on increasing as read stream forwards data. Anyways, I got the answer. Its posted below. Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16013228/5732327).

In addition, Node.js 10 added support for asynchronously iterating over readable streams.
However **async-iterators not yet have support for readline** ([ref](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/18904)).

Example for async-iterators from [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_symbol_asynciterator):

```
const fs = require('fs');

async function print(readable) {
  readable.setEncoding('utf8');
  let data = '';
  for await (const k of readable) {
    data += k;
  }
  console.log(data);
}

print(fs.createReadStream('file')).catch(console.error);
```