# What is the most efficient way to read heavy files(>~10Gb) using Node.JS(LTS)?

Tags: node.js, file, memory-mapped-files

What is the most efficient way to read heavy files(>~10Gb) using Node.JS(LTS)?

Essentially in today's world, I need to read the file content, parse each line to a known data-structure , perform certain validations, and push the data-structure into the database(SQL Server). I do it using C#(memory-mapped files). It works pretty well because I am able to read the file in chunks (in parallel).

I am planning to migrate the solution to Node(and MongoDB) for a business use-case.

Any leads/suggestions?

Environment:

I am using a 64-bit Windows OS, x64 based processor, 8Gigs of RAM

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is usually referred to as **streams** in `node.js`.

You can read or write very large files with **streams** by processing portions of it.

Here are a few links that could help you to get started.

[Parsing huge logfiles in Node.js - read in line-by-line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23695940/3626796)

[Using Node.js to Read Really, Really Large Datasets & Files](https://itnext.io/using-node-js-to-read-really-really-large-files-pt-1-d2057fe76b33)

[Read large text files in nodejs](https://coderwall.com/p/ohjerg/read-large-text-files-in-nodejs)

Comment: Additionally... there are often standard filter streams and stream parsers for handling common file types.