# Couldn't read webpack bundle stats... RangeError [ERR_FS_FILE_TOO_LARGE]: File size is greater than 2 GB

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to use the [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) package but get this error message

```
Couldn't read webpack bundle stats from "/.../stats.json":
RangeError [ERR_FS_FILE_TOO_LARGE]: File size (3538152929) is greater than 2 GB
```

The solutions I've found are all around managing how the files is being read, but since it's being done within a package I'm not sure how to approach it. I was hoping I could adjust a setting but apparently that's a [no go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70904699/7613388).

Background: I'm exploring the bundle(s)created from a vuejs app with (obviously) large bundles using webpack 5