# how i can read files in folder node js advanced?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i will use this script and i get some bugs
because i will read 10 million line and detected him
to some function and i can't solve this but i think if if anyone solve this not add all to area and we will solve this bugs
thanks for help me

```
const fs = require('fs');
//joining path of directory 
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'Documents');
//passsing directoryPath and callback function
fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
   //handling error
   if (err) {
       return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
   } 
   //listing all files using forEach
   files.forEach(function (file) {
       // Do whatever you want to do with the file
       console.log(file); 
   });
});


error :-
<--- Last few GCs --->

[1564:00000280010DEA30]    80020 ms: Mark-sweep 2055.1 (2057.5) -> 2055.1 (2058.8) MB, 2339.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.159, current mu = 0.093) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[1564:00000280010DEA30]    82029 ms: Mark-sweep 2056.4 (2058.8) -> 2056.4 (2060.3) MB, 1874.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.118, current mu = 0.067) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================
```

Comment: it seems your directory either has a huge number of files or few very huge files, in both cases a lot of data is in-memory while the whole process. Try to do it in batch, like 20 files at a time or something.

Comment: if i try 10 file or 100k line its work with me if file big not working

Answer (score 2):

Starting from node `>= v12.12.0` [async readdir is supported](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_dir), which will not load all the entries into memory:

```
const fs = require('fs');

async function processDir(path) {
  const dir = await fs.promises.opendir(path);
  for await (const entry of dir) {
    console.log(entry.name); // process the directory entry here
  }
}

processDir('./path-to-dir').catch(console.error);
```

---

EDIT:
As the files themselves are big, you also need to process those asynchronously instead of loading their contents into memory at once. There are a number of ways to do this, this SO-question addresses the same issue: [Parsing huge logfiles in Node.js - read in line-by-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010915/parsing-huge-logfiles-in-node-js-read-in-line-by-line)

So for example you can do (still needs error-handling but should give you a start):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const LineByLineReader = require('line-by-line');

async function processDir(pathToDir) {
    const dir = await fs.promises.opendir(pathToDir);
    const processFilePromises = [];
    for await (const entry of dir) {
        processFilePromises.push(processFile(path.resolve(pathToDir, entry.name)));
    }
    return Promise.all(processFilePromises);
}

async function processFile(file) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const lr = new LineByLineReader(file);
        lr.on('line', (line) => {
           // process the line here
        });

        lr.on('end', () => {
            resolve();
        });
    })
}

processDir('./path-to-your-dir').catch(console.error);
```

Comment: i do that but not work with me same bugs i use in same code
 nath_var= fs.readFileSync(`${dir.path}/${entry.name}`, 'utf-8').replace(/\r/g, '').split('\n').filter(Boolean); its current ?

Comment: It seems that the files themselves are really big then -> there are already questions on SO to tackle this: see this for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010915/parsing-huge-logfiles-in-node-js-read-in-line-by-line